# Type for difference of two absolute values

Tags: type-theory

I always see that people in the fields consider confusing vectors with positions as a severe error [in one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384927) and [n dimensions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/62789/35556). Recently I have also [encoutered a timedelta type in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952551). By increadably inadequate reaction and severe punishment, I realize that people in the fields taboo answering why is the difference.

Might be the computer scientists are different and can tell the principal difference among the types. Does time differece has different nature from the datetime? Does `a = b-c` has the same nature as the `b` and `c`? In which case do you introduce a new type? Why do [they say that `a` has the same type in case of int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952551/why-dont-we-have-intdelta-a-qustin-about-timedelta#comment29699311_19952607) but not in case of time or position?

Is this related to dimensional analysis?  It seems like dimensional analysis would say that `a` has the same unit of measurement (and therefore the type) as the `b` and `c` in `a=b-c`.  Is this correct?

Comment: Hey Val, you just rolled back a bunch of the edits I made to improve the question.  Your rollback re-introduced spelling mistakes, grammar errors, rant-y statements that are not relevant here ("increadably inadequate reaction and severe punishment" - come on), and other problems.  Please don't do that.  This is a community site with shared ownership of questions.  Please see [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/editing) to understand the site model, and don't gratuitously roll back edits that others have made to improve your question.

Comment: Your "ownership" removed a half of my question. I have told you that my question is more general than time alone. Might be you will invent the questions for me next time?

Comment: I don't think my statement is really worth a separate answer, so I reply with a comment. The problem is as simple as this: the difference between two dates is not a date. The difference between two ints is an int. I don't think this has anything to do with dimensional analysis, as it makes sense to talk about it in the context of types for which addition and multiplication is defined.

Comment: @Daniil How did you determine that diff of dates is not a date? By circular argument? What about the spacial dimensions (vectors vs. positions)? Which units of measurment escape the addition/multiplication? Particularly, how addition/multiplication is not defined for the time if it is actually defined?

Comment: @Val, Well, consider what do we actually mean by dates? Date is some specific point in time, e.g. May 1 or May 7th. The difference of those dates, however, is not a point in time itself, it's a whole week. For example one might say "What were you doing on the 1st of May", *but* "What were you doing between the 1st of May and the 7th of May".

Comment: I am not sure what exactly do you mean by "escapes the addition". Subtraction is not defined on dates, but in Python in particular you have this "-" which returns a completely different thing based on different arguments. In a statically-typed language you wouldn't have such an operator.

Comment: @Daniil Consider a point in space. Inter-point distance is not a point! How can we have the same type for both (e.g. in VHDL)? The dates are a kind of time, they store amount of time since AD or "1 Jan. 1970", likewise you measure **position as distance from the origin**. Now, look into physical units (in dimensional analysis) and find the *time* as one them. Finally, what is the point to ban timediff in static languages after `Date is some specific point in time. The difference of those dates, however, is not a point in time itself`? Do you make up these rules as you go or it is a deep CS?

Comment: Firstly, I didn't know that VHDL has built-in types for points, I'll need to research VHDL more to answer that part of your question. Secondly, in physics (unlike in computer programming) you usually deal with time *intervals*, like "5 seconds" or "10 minutes". Thirdly, static languages do not "ban" time difference. For example, look at Haskell: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/old-time-1.1.0.1/docs/System-Time.html different time for date and for time difference. Lastly, I don't make those rules up, it's just common sense. Imagine that b=1st of Jan and c=7th of Jan. What would be `a=b-c`?

Comment: @Daniil I think that questions must be asked by people who do not understand. I am not going to distract the VHDL designers asking why do they did a reasonable design (from my point of view) just because this is news for you. I ask here for the general principle. I wonder how you have timediff in Haskell without the timediff operator. There is nothing simpler than to compute "1st Jan" - "7th Jan" = -6 days. Now, applying your "common sense" (I see that you was banned to consider the spacial positions), timediff1-timediff2 is not a timediff -- it is another type! Right?

Comment: @Val, Haskell *does* have a timediff function, in fact, it takes two dates and returns a *time difference*. '-6 days' is not a date in the same sense as '1th of January, 12:00 GMT' is. The subtraction on timediffs can be easily defined and I think it's reasonable that the sum or subtraction of two timediffs is a timediff.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11753/discussion-between-daniil-and-val)

Comment: @Daniil You say that static-typed languages cannot have "-" operation for dates and then come up with Haskel as a counterexample. I do not understand why this is done at all. The difference '-6 days' has the same structure (set of fields) as the '1th Jan 12:00'. You store both in the variables of same type. You leave all differences to the names of variables. All type differences I see so far are due to your tradition, double standards and circular argument. Though they often replace logic, they are opposite to it. I need a more serious argument than simple "listen to me, types are different".

Answer (score 1):

You already got a reasonable answer, [the last time you asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19952551/781723).  For instance

> In a nutshell, because datetimes have additional metadata (e.g. timezone) and behave non-linearly, while timedeltas are always linear and have no timezone, etc attached. For example, adding two one-day timedeltas always produces a two-day timedelta, while adding a one-day timedelta to a given datetime may or may not advance the datetime to the next day depending on what value the datetime has (i.e. daylight savings, leap seconds, etc)  [Joe Kington]

Some friendly advice: if you really want an answer, take care to avoid ranting.  Approach things with an open mind and from the perspective that you want to learn, not from the perspective that you already know the correct answer and anyone who disagrees with you must be wrong.  Try to be a little less aggressive and a little more humble and open to learning.  I have edited your question above to remove the ranting for you.

Comment: What makes you think that I approached with a ready-made answer? I was really sure that there is a serious reason that I am not aware of and was very curious to know. You should see that I had no objections toward the right answer (thanks of picking it). I just do not buy the first nonsense thrown on my. Everybody must point to the obvious nonsense in responses and demand to fix them/elaborate! How can you deny it as "closed mindedness" and "ranting"?! Everything is vise-versa. My mind is much more open than of peoples' who force me to accept wrong things.

Comment: I also do not understand why did you remove the space part of my question.

Comment: @Val, are you a bot?